# Mule MANIFEST.MF

Tags: mule, manifest.mf

Is there any way to extract MANIFEST.MF in mule?? I would like to get version related information like, build version, timestamp, version etc. I'm creating API to get these build information.

other than MANIFEST.MF, is there any other way to get mule build version information?

I would appreciate your reply.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use to extract Mule version or Server ID, for example:

```
Manifest mf = MuleManifest.getManifest();
Attributes att = mf.getMainAttributes();
out --> MuleManifest.getProductDescription();
out --> MuleManifest.getProductMoreInfo();
out --> MuleManifest.getBuildNumber();
```

I hope to help;